# python module import error when running, while imported fine in interactive mode

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a clean python3.6 virtualenv in a native python2 environment via anaconda3, and I'm able to import some module in the interactive mode:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from skimage.transform import resize
>>>
```

however, this seems to break when I run in a non-interactive mode by calling:

```
(py3)$ python filename.py
...
File "path_to_module.py", line 6, in <module>
    from skimage.transform import resize
...
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by path_to_pyenv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Note this error does not occur exclusively by importing this particular skimage module, so i guess this is a generic error.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

turns out that the native matplotlib coming with Anaconda was outdated, so i fixed this error by upgrading it:

```
pip install matplotlib --upgrade
```